# How do I transform and reshape the data in this CSV?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a csv file that has the following layout:

```
Website Text  
A       B
```

In the first column there is a website, and the second is text I scraped from it.
This is a 1gb size file.

I need to somehow go over each line row of Text, irrelevant of the website and combine it into one cell. So for example:

```
Website Text  
A       Mary
B       had a little lamb
```

Would become:

```
  Text  
  Mary had a little lamb
```

I have tried multiple things, pandas wont work because the file is too large to have in the memory all at once, and I don't know how to use pyspark/spark to do it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just read the file one line at a time and write the text to another file?

Comment: @Goyo I don't understand what you mean exactly?

Comment: your question of how to use pyspark is too broad (assuming you have never used it before). You need to learn the basics first.